# Which is better; Multiple CTE's in a single query or multiple views joined?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, view, common-table-expression

I am currently in the progress of a database migration from MS Access to SQL Server. To improve performance of a specific query, I am translating from access to T-SQL and executing server-side. The query in question is essentially made up of almost 15 subqueries branching off in to different directions with varying levels of complexity. The top level query is a culmination (final Select) of all of these queries.

Without actually going into the specifics of the fields and relationships in my queries, I want to ask a question on a generic example.

Take the following:

```
                                               Top Level Query
                                                      |
                                           ___________|___________
                                          |                       |
                                       Query 1   <---------->   Query 2
                 _________________________|          Views?       |_______________________________
                |                |                                          |                     |
           Query 1.1          Query 1.2                                 Query 2.1           Query 2.2
        ________|______                                               ______|________
       |               |                                             |               |
  Query 1.1.1        Query 1.1.2                                Query 2.1.1      Query 2.1.2
       |               |                                             |               |
      ...             ...                                           ...             ...
```

I am attempting to convert the above MS Access query structure to T-SQL, whilst maximising performance. So far I have converted all of **Query1** Into a single query starting from the bottom and working my way up. I have achieved by using CTE's to represent every single subquery and then finally selected from this entire CTE tree to produce **Query1**. Due to the original design of the query, there is a high level of dependency between the subqueries.

Now my question is quite simple actually. With regards to **Query2**, should I continue to use this same method within the same query window or should I make both **Query1** and **Query2** seperate entities  (Views) and then do a select from each? Or should I just continue adding more CTE's and then get the final **Top Level Query** result from this one super query?

This is an extremely bastardised version of the actual query, I am working with which has a large number of calculated fields and more subquery levels.

What do you think is the best approach here?

Comment: _Best_ is pretty undefined. SQL server will likely compile both options to exactly the same execution plan. And regarding ease of development/debugging/not having tons of views on the server, that's up to you

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to say for sure from a diagram like this, but I suspect that you want to use Views for a number of reasons.

1) If the sub-query/view is used in more than one place there is a high chance that caching will allow for results to be shared in more than one place, but it is not as strong effect as a CTE but can be mitigated with a materialized query

2) It is easy turn a view into a materialized view.  Then you get huge bonus if it is used multiple times or is used many times before it needs to be refreshed.

3) If you find a slow part it will be isolated to one view -- then you can optimize and change that small section easier.

I would recommend using views for EVERY sub-view if you can.  Unless you can demonstrate (via execution plan or testing) that the CTE runs faster.

> Final note as someone who has migrated Access to SQL in the past.  Access encourages more sub-queries than needed with modern SQL and windowing functions.  It is very likely with some analysis these access queries can be made much simpler.  *Try to find cases where you can roll them up to the parent query*

Comment: 1) All subqueries are just used for this query. Nowhere else. Only the Top Level query is used in multiple places.
2) Yes.
3) Indeed!

Regarding your recommendation on nesting all of these views, Isn't a lot of views generally considered bad practice? If I were to make anything views, it would only be Query 1 and Query 2.
@Hogan

Comment: There is nothing about nesting a lot of views that makes it bad practice -- just having lots of nested queries is bad.  Try and reduce those if you can.  That they are views does not matter at all to the compiler and in some cases can increase the speed.

Comment: 1) Nested views do have a negative performance impact. If you nest too deeply (the number is variable depending upon complexity), SQL Server will not produce a good cardinality estimate, and thus a bad query plan will be used. CTEs have a similar problem. 2) Query results are not cached by SQL Server.

Comment: @alroc -- you just contradicted yourself -- if both views and ctes have the same problem (don't nest to deep) then it is not a negative of views.  Since it effects the same on both choices it is not worthy of consideration when picking one.   I think you are talking about a different caching than I am -- there are many potential types of caches that can have effect -- disk cache, memory cache, query plan cache etc etc.  We probably have to align on which type you are talking about and which type I'm talking about to reach an understanding of my (way to brief) statement.

Comment: I didn't contradict myself. I stated that both nested views and nested CTEs share the same problem. I didn't advocate for one solution over the other; in fact I would advocate against using either in this scenario. Re caching, you said _high chance that caching will allow for results to be shared_ which I take to mean as caching the results of a subquery (the data returned by it).

Comment: I feel like this is derailing a little bit. @alroc to answer your query about the complexity of the nesting, In my particular case, each subquery level is massively complex. There are multiple calculated fields in each query that are calculated upon further, in the query above.
Each subquery is self-contained and only used by the query above. This design came from a very knowledgeable Access developer who has little experience with developing in SQL code. So he's done some very clever workarounds to getting better performance out of access 2002, techniques which haven't aged well.

Comment: @RikuDas -- Have you looked at windowing functions?  I'm 95% sure you can get rid of at least two levels of sub-queries if they are used.

Answer (score 0):

A query you submit, or a "view" is all the same thing.

Your BASIC simple question stands!

Should you use a query on query, or a use a CTE?

Well, first, lets get rid of some confusing you have here.

A CTE is great for eliminaton of the need to build a query, save the query (say as a view) AND THEN query against it.

However, in your question we are mixing up TWO VERY different issues.

Are you doing a query against a query, or in YOUR case using a sub-query? While these two things SEEM simular, they really at not!!!

In the case of a sub-query, using a CTE will in fact save you the pain of having to build a separate query/view and saving that query. In this case, you are I suppose doing a query on query, but it REALLY a sub query. From a performance point of view, I don't believe you  find any difference, so do  what works best for you. I do in some ways like adopting CTE's  since THEN you have have the "whole thing" in one spot. And updates to the whole mess occurs in one place. This can especially be an advantage if you have several sites. So to update things, you ONLY have to update this one huge big saved "thing". I do find this a signficant advantage.

The advantages of breaking out into separate views (as opposed to using CTE's) can often be the simple issue that how do you eat a elephant?
Answer: One bite at a time.

However, I in fact consider the conept and approahc of a sub-query a DIFFERENT issue then building a query on query. One of the really big reasons to using CTE'S in sql server, is SQL server has one REALLY big limitation compared to Access SQL. That limiation of course is being able to re-use derived columns. 
eg this:

```
SELECT ID, Company, State, TaxRate, Purchased, Payments,
(Purchased - Payments) as Balance,
(Balance * TaxRate) as BalanceWithTax
FROM Customers
```

Of course in T-SQL, you can't re-use expression like you can in Access T-SQL. So the above is a GREAT use of CTE'S. Balance in t-sql cannot be re-used. So you are having to constant repeat expressions in t-sql (my big pet peeve with t-sql). Using a CTE means we CAN use the above ability to repeat a expression.

So I tend to think of the CTE solving two issues, and you should keep these concepts seperate:
I want to eleiminate the need for a query on query, and that includes sub-queries.

So, sure, using  CTE for above is a good use.

The SECOND use case is the abilty to repeat use expession columns. This is VERY painful in T-SQL, and CTE's go a long way to reducing this pain point (Access SQL is still far better), but CTE's are at least very helpfull.

So, from a performance point of view, using CTE's to eliminate sub query should not effect perfomance, and as noted you can saving having to create 2-5 seperate queries for this to work.

Then there is a query on query (especially in the above use case of being able to re-use columns in expressions. In this case, I believe some performance advantages exist, but again, likely not enough to justify one approach or the other. So once  again, adopting CTE's should be which road is LESS work for you! (but for a very nasty say sub-query that sums() and does some real work, and THEN you need to re-use that columns, then that is really when CTE's shine here.

So as a general coding approach, I used CTE's to advoid query on query (but NOT a sub quer s you are doing). And I use CTE's to gain re-use of a complex expression column.

Using CTE's to eliminate having sub-queries is not really all that great of a benefit. (I mean, just shove the sub-query into the main query - MOST of the time a CTE will not help you).

So, using CTE's just for the concept of a sub-query is not all that great of a advantage. You can, but I don't see great gains from a developer poitn of view. However, in the case of query on query (to gain re-use of column expressions?). Well then the CTE's elemintes the need for a query against the same table/query.

So, for just sub-queries, I can't say CTE's are huge advantage. But for re-use of column expressions, then you MUST either do a query on a query (say a saved view), and THEN you gain re-use of the columns as expressions to be used in additional expressions.

While this is somewhat opinion?
CTE'S ability to allow re-use of columns is their use case, because this elimiantes the need to create a sepeate view. It is not so much that you elimited the need for a seperate view (query on query), but that you gained used of a column exprssion for re-use is the main benefit here.

So, you certainly can use CTE's to eliminate having to create views (yes, a good idea), but in your case you likly could have just used sub-queries anyway, and the CTE's are not really required. For column re-use, you have NO CHOICE in the matter. Since you MUST use a query on query for column expression re-use, the the CTE's will eliminate this need. In your case (at least so far) you really did not need to use a CTE's and you were not being forced to in regards to your solution. For column re-use  you have zero choice - you ARE being forced to query on query - so a CTE's eliminates this need.

As far as I can tell, so far you don't really need necessary to use a CTE unless the issue is being able to re-use some columns in other expressions like we could/can in Access sql.

If column re-use is the goal? Then yes, CTE's are a great solution. So it more of a column re-use issue then that of choosing to use query on query. If you did not have the additional views in Access, then no question that adopting CTE's to keep a similar approach and design makes a lot of sense. So the motivation of column re-use is what we lost by going to sql server, and CTE's do a lot to regain this ability.